# Change rotation point in grease pencil

Tags: vertices, transforms, grease-pencil

If I have a stroke with 3 vertices and I select the right 2 vertices then rotate it rotates from the middle of between the 2 points. Is there any way I can have it rotate from the middle vertex?

Comment: you can change the Transform Pivot Point (top-middle of editor window) to 3D Cursor, then place the cursor where you want the pivot to be. Note that the 3D cursor might not be visible in GP mode, but you can enable it in Overlays (top-right)

Comment: That was it, could not see the 3D cursor - thanks!